# Getting ALL last_inserted_ids

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysql mulitple row insert-select statement with last_insert_id()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054240/mysql-mulitple-row-insert-select-statement-with-last-insert-id)

Is there a possibility to get the **last_inserted_ids** ?

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE employee (
    ->      id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->      name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    ->      PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ->  );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql>
mysql> INSERT INTO employee (name) VALUES ('A'),
    ->                                    ('B'),
    ->                                    ('C'),
    ->                                    ('D'),
    ->                                    ('E'),
    ->                                    ('F');
```

Now how can I get the ids of 'A', 'B', 'C' ... ?
Does MySQL offer me a simple way to do this ? like it does with one row

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```